# Как перейти по javascript ссылки в библиотеки java jsoup?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, jsoup

Парсим сайт https://bankrot.fedresurs.ru/. Возникла проблема при парсинге сообщений арбитражного управляющего при переходе на следующию страницу с сообщениями (вот пример https://bankrot.fedresurs.ru/ArbitrManagerCard.aspx?ID=9a09227a-0162-4e44-ab18-7a78860a69c1). Как в jsoup перейти по javascript ссылки?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос точно связан с JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

JSOUP получает только статический контент - строку-HTML. Никаких действий выполнить нельзя. Вам надо посмотреть что происходит при нажатии на кнопки - может там просто другая страница открывается? Если нет и запускается JS и он же и всё наполняет данными - изучите что он делает - возможно получится отловить нужный сетевой запрос. Если не выйдет - то надо идти максимально сложным и безумнотрудоёмким путём - использовать эмуляторы браузера (Selenium) и переписывать весь код под него.